# trying to create different cells in same table view - but can't figure out how to code in the tableviewcontroller

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I have created a tableview with multiple prototype (4) cells in order to display different content in each cell but being a newb - I am not clear on how to then code this in the tableviewcontroller to pull data into the multiple cells (just using multiple simple arrays with one data point for each label for now to test it) but I can only get the data to populate in the first cell - and not clear how to code to get the data into the remaining cells.  I created 4 separate customtableviewcell files as well.  Can someone point me in the right direction on  how to code so I can get data into the four separate prototype cells?  I need it to be able scroll as it won;t all fit on the the screen which is why I chose table view to do this - but there will only ever be these four sections in the view (with different data depending on what you pushed to get here)  should I not be using tableview?  if I should be using something different like a view controller with 4 views instead? will it scroll so the user can see all sections?  Thanks in advance for any help and suggestions.

Comment: did you implement `numberOfSections` and `numberOfRowsInSection:` of you `UITableViewDataSource`?

Answer (score 1):

You should assign unique **Identifier** to the each cell in the Storyboard. Then, you can populate appropriate cells like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   switch (indexPath.section)
   {
      case 0:
      {
          MyCustomCell1 *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell_1"];
          // Configure cell
          return cell;
      }


      case 1:

      ...

      default: return nil;
   }
}
```

Consider creating custom subclasses of **UITableViewCell** to provide handy **IBOutlets**.

Comment: ok this looks like a great answer - but another newb question, how do I put my arrays with the data into "sections" so when I use switch and it looks for a section it pulls the right data?

Comment: For example - here is how my array is set up, just for testing the tableviewcontroller so its quite simplistic at the moment:  //this would be the first section to populate the first custom prototype cell
    var wineryNames = ["Glenora Wine Cellars"]
    var wineryAddress = ["5435 Route 14, Dundee, NY 14837"]
    var phoneNumber = ["(800) 243-5513"]
    
    // this would be the data for the second cell
    var tastingFee = ["$5 for a flight of 5.  $3 given back with purchase"]
    var dryMust = ["2013 Stainless Steel Pinot Blanc"]
    var sweetMust = ["2011 Willow White"]

Comment: No need to use arrays with just one object in it, newb :) For testing you can setup labels of your cells in switch statement: cell.label.text = "Glenora Wine Cellars".

Comment: haha :-)  thanks will give it a shot that way - assuming since in reality I will just be pulling one data point per label in this view I can do the same when I want the variable data and pull it directly in the cell statement.  thanks for the good input

Answer (score 0):

(1) You need 4 cells. So, prepare 4 custom cells by creating subclass of UITableViewCell. You will know how to create custom cell by search on google.

(2) Set number of sections to 1.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}
```

(3) Set desired height for each cell

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    switch(indexPath.row)
    {
        case 0:
        {
            return 40;
        }

        case 1:
        {
            return 50;
        }

        case 2:
        {
            return 30;
        }

        case 3:
        {
            return 45;
        }

        default:
        {
            return 0; // Default case
        }
    }
}
```

(4) Set contents of each cell. The data will come from your data source i.e. Array or Dictionary.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"CellIdentifier%d%d",indexPath.section,indexPath.row];

    if(indexPath.row == 0)
    {
        CustomCell1 *objCustomCell1 = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        if(objCustomCell1 == nil)
        {
            objCustomCell1 = [[CustomCell1 alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
            objCustomCell1.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        }

        // Set row specific data here...

        NSDictionary *dicObj = [arrYourDataSource objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        objCustomCell1.myLabel.text = [dicObj objectForKey:@"your key"];

        return objCustomCell1;
    }

    else if(indexPath.row == 1)
    {
        CustomCell2 *objCustomCell2 = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        if(objCustomCell2 == nil)
        {
            objCustomCell2 = [[CustomCell2 alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
            objCustomCell2.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        }

        // Set row specific data here...

        NSDictionary *dicObj = [arrYourDataSource objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        UIImage *theImage = [UIImage imageNamed:[dicObj objectForKey:@"your key"]];
        objCustomCell2.myImageView.image = theImage;

        return objCustomCell2;
    }

    // Do same for remaining 2 rows.

    return nil;
}
```

First do this and then add comment. We will move ahead.